# i++ animation for javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck animate the same first frame, when I want to call out to i++ but for whatever reason I'm not able to load in the next variable.  My setTimeout function fires every 3 seconds and should load in the next li in the view.

```
//set animation

function animate() {
var set = $(".1,.2,.3,.4");

var i = 0;
$(set).find('li:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').removeClass().find('li:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').addClass("active");
//$(set).find("li:first").addClass('active');

};


setTimeout(function(){
animate();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: i=0, whenever you call the function.

Comment: setTimeout fires every __every__ 3 seconds, or __after__ 3 seconds?

Comment: "My setTimeout function fires every 3 seconds" - Nope. It fires once, after a delay of three seconds.

Comment: oh maybe that's the problem I want it to continue to fire every three seconds.

Comment: Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` if you want it to fire more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` waits for *n* milliseconds (in your case, 3000) and then calls your function once. Look into `setInterval` instead.

You also need to move `i` outside of `animate`. In your current implementation, you declare a variable `i = 0` each time you call `animate()`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Scope issue. You declare

```
var i = 0;
```

within the function every time you call `animate()` so it resets to 0 --> first frame.

Declare the variable outside of the function so it doesn't reset to 0.